# How q is reached as inference, even when ~q is in the premise?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwJEN.png) screen grab from the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1259006395), Elements of Discrete Mathematics by C L Liu. On the first chapter about Sets and Propositions, under the heading `THEORY OF INFERENCES` there is an example problem.

The problem states,

> **Example 1.26** Show that `q` is a valid inference from the premises `p -> q`, `p v q` and `~q`

Though the answer is derived using the laws (as it is evident in the screen grab), the confusion I have is, how can possibly `q` be inferred when we know `~q` is infact true? Is it due to the combination of illegitimate premises `p -> q` and `p v q`?

Comment: More generaly, `z` is a valid inference from the premises `p -> z`, `p v q` and `~q`.

Comment: The premises are inconsistent. For a simpler example, note that $p$ and $\neg p$ can both be derived from the premise $p \wedge \neg p$.

Comment: Thanks, Please post as answer

Comment: The reason is the "interaction" of $\lnot q$ with the first two premises : $p \to q$ and $p \lor q$. Consider the second one : either *(i)* $p$ is True, in which case from $p \to q$ we derive $q$ and thus a contradiction with $\lnot q$, or *(ii)* $q$ is True, in which case we have imemdiately the contradiction.

Comment: In general, from contradictory premises, we can derive everything; see [Ex Falso Quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know ~q true.  We can assume ~q as true.  Then we can derive q as true also (given the other assumptions and valid rules of inferences).  Thus, we can determine that the premise set is not consistent.